# MongoDB. Undefined record inserted. Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

Im newbie in MongoDB. Once started immediately got the error.
I have a simple code

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongotest',
    function(err, db) {
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB!');
        // using the db connection object, save the collection 'testing' to
        // a separate variable:
        var collection = db.collection('testing');
        // isert a new item using the collection's insert function:
        collection.insert({
            'title': 'Snowcrash'
        }, function(err, docs) {
            // on successful insertion, log to the screen the new
            // collection's details:
            console.log(docs.length + ' record inserted.');
            console.log(docs[0].title + ' – ' + docs[0]._id);
            // finally close the connection:
            db.close();
        });
    });
```

and here is the [error message](http://pastebin.com/1g22jJex)

[image]

Help me please to understand what this error and how to fix it. If you do not complicate.

MongoDB version 3.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create connection and insert to MongoDB

I use MongoDB 3.2.0 and mongodb node.js driver 2.1.14

Install Node.js MongoDB driver and BSON with npm

```
npm install mongodb bson
```

and INSERT operation looks like this

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var bson = require('bson');

// Create Connection
var server = new mongodb.Server('127.0.0.1', '27017', {});
var client = new mongodb.Db('mydb', server, {w:1});

client.open(function(error){
    if(error)
        throw error;
    // Create MongoDB Collection
    client.collection('mongodb_insert', function(error, collection) {
        if(error)
            throw error;
        console.log('Connection!')
        // CREATE/INSERT Operation
        collection.insert(
            {
                "key": "value",
                "key1": "value1"
            },
            {safe: true},
            function(error, document)
            {
                if(error)
                    throw error;
                console.log(document);
            }
        )
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you should replace the former code with this

```
console.log(docs.ops.length + ' record inserted.');
console.log(docs.ops[0].title + ' – ' + docs.ops[0]._id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used  module `mongodb 2.0.49` and  `database mongodb3.0`

After Inserting to testing collection, docs is not the documents of testing collection.

docs is result of query.

It will looks like

```
{ result: { ok: 1, n: 1 },
  ops: [ { 'it's you query'} ],
  insertedCount: 1,
  insertedIds: [ 'blah blah blah' ] }
```

So, docs is not Array but json.

That's why docs[0] is undefined("docs is not array!!!!")

Comment: at the moment it looks like this `collection.insert({ 'title': 'Snowcrash' }` It is an object. Into MongoDB can record objects? But at the moment for some reason he does not insert

Comment: Do you means that query doesn't work? Remove "console.log(docs.length + ' record inserted.'); console.log(docs[0].title + ' – ' + docs[0]._id);"! Then it work!